# .Net Remoting not working in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

We have a server application (developed using .Net 1.1, C#) which listen the port 8086 and the client application, before starting will handshake with this server using remoting.

The application is working fine in almost all environments - Windows 2000/2003/2008/XP/Vista.

Now we are facing an issue with Windows 7.

When we are staring the server, it’s opening the port and will be listening to clients, but when try to send a request from a client who is running in other OS, it gives a message that server is not running.

We disabled the proxy, gave the exceptions for proxy but all went in vain. On further analysis we found that the system is having multiple connectivity (LAN, Bluetooth &WIFI).

When we checked the TCP port using netstat –a it showed the Local Address as 0.0.0.0:8086. So we disabled/removed the Bluetooth & WiFi option and tried again then also netstat is showing LocalAddress 0.0.0.0:8086.

How to go ahead in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By Local Address do you mean when you use `localhost`?

Comment: Its one of the column shown when will give netstat -a command in command line. The columns shown when we execute netstat -a include 

"Proto" "Local Address" "Foreign Address" "State"

Answer (score 0):

Do a network capture using Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark to better understand the underlying TCP/IP packets. That can show what's up easily.